# CefSharp Executescriptasync Return Loop Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to pull specific tag values ​​on a page I created for experiment.I'm new to using Cefsharp. And I'm trying to experiment to improve myself.I was stuck for about two days in the EvaluateScriptAsync section.

I am trying to capture the values ​​of the buttons in the specific label on the page I prepared.I run the following codes by pressing a button.My page has 3 buttons with the same label.However, it prints only one of them.

```
<input type="button" id ="button1" value="First Button">
<input type="button" id ="button2" value="Second Button">
<input type="button" id ="button3" value="Third Button">
```

These are the buttons I'm trying to find.

```
string script = @"(function() { " +
    "var button = document.querySelectorAll('input[type = \"button\"]'); " +
    "if(button != null) {for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {  return button[i].value; 
    }}else{alert('not found!');}" +
"})();";

 chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(a =>{
       var response = a.Result;
       if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
       {
           string print = (string)response.Result;
           MessageBox.Show(print.ToString());
       }
 }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I have tried many.I think I'm making a mistake in the javascript part.I've read most of the similar topics.But I could not find a solution.

```
output : First Button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  The EvaluateScriptAsync funciton can only return 1 value or a string so I made sure to convert the results in JavaScript to a JSON string object.

Then when you retrieve the result back in C# land, you can then use JSON to convert it back to an object (in this case a list of strings) and perform any operations you need on the data.

```
// Step 01: Generate a HTML page
var htmlPage = @"
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello!!</p>
        <input type='button' id='button1' value='First Button'>
        <input type='button' id='button2' value='Second Button'>
        <input type='button' id='button3' value='Third Button'>
    </body>
</html>";

// Step 02: Load the Page
m_chromeBrowser.LoadHtml(htmlPage, "http://customrendering/");

// Step 03: Get list of buttons on page from C# land
var jsScript = @"

// define a temp function to retrieve button text
function tempFunction() {
   var result = [];
   var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');

   for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {   
      result.push(list[i].value);
   }

   // Important: convert object to json string before returning to C#  
   return JSON.stringify(result);
}

// Now execute the temp function and returns result back to C#
tempFunction();";

var task = m_chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript);

task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        var response = t.Result;

        if (response.Success == true)
        {
            // Use JSON.net to convert to object;
            MessageBox.Show(response.Result.ToString());
        }
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Looking at your JavaScript code sample, the problem with your code is that in your loop you have a return statement that will just return the 1st button value it comes across.  Thats your problem.

If you want to interact with the resulting list in C# land you will need to convert it back from a JSON string.  Just go to nuget and install the 'Newtonsoft.Json' package into your project.

Then you can write something like:

```
// C# land    
var list = new List<string>();
list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response.Result.ToString());
```

Comment: I didn't know that the "EvaluateScriptAsync" would only turn once.When I deleted the return code, which is in the loop, it didn't work.It worked once when I added the return.Thank you very much for the sample code block you provided.I've tried many examples, but I never thought of converting to JSON format.
It performs the function I want.As output, she outputted all the results in one string at once.So if I want output one by one, can I create a array again with json.parse and pull it out?

Comment: Yeah, outputting to JSON means that you can return anything from JavaScript from a simple string to a list of numbers or even a list of objects with all sorts or properties.  It means that when you get the data back on the C# side you will be able to interact with them instead of just messign with a string.  Deffo the way to go.  For you, inside Visual Studio, just go to nuget and install Newtonsoft JSON into your project.  I will update my answer with a quick code sample.

Comment: Returning a single value from a function is a fundamental of the JavaScript language. The same applies to all the CefSharp functions that interact with JavaScript. I will point out that you can return a list directly without JSON, you will get an instance of List<object>, remembering that JavaScript is not strongly typed so you could return a list of differing types hence the use of the use of List<object>. No objection to using JSON if that better suites your use case.

Comment: @Check78 Glad to hear you have got it sorted.

Comment: Hi Alex. (@amaitland) - Just wanted to say, thanks for all the work and support you put into this package

Comment: @amaitland My message was deleted. I don't know why it was deleted. But thank you again for the information you provided.